# Subquery using JSON_TABLE gives ORA-0600 error

Tags: oracle

Oracle 12.

I run this query:

```
select *
from   json_table('[1244, 1188]', '$[*]' columns(id number path '$'));
```

And it works, but when I try the following

```
select *
from   some_table
where  id in
       ( select *
         from   json_table('[1244, 1188]', '$[*]' columns(id number path '$')));
```

I get an error

> ORA-0600: internal error code, arguments: [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s]
>
> Cause: This is the generic internal error number for Oracle program exceptions. It indicates that a process has encountered a low-level, unexpected condition. The first argument is the internal message number. This argument and the database version number are critical in identifying the root cause and the potential impact to your system.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Report this error to Oracle Support Services. It is working fine in [db,.fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=976e402b1b94fb7308d71917301aa751)

Comment: yeah, that is an internal oracle error, you have to contact support.

Comment: What is the full ORA-0600 message? There should be numeric values in place of one or two of those `%s` placeholders.

Comment: Does that `select *` return a single column with the same datatype as the `id` column you are matching it to? Normally `select *` returns multiple columns and so would not match an `id`.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - JSON_TABLE returns the columns written explicitly in its COLUMNS clause. In the OP's code, the COLUMNS clause creates a single column, ID, of data type NUMBER.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - regarding your other comment, the full error message includes the following: `SQL Error: ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [qmxptAddDependency1], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []`. Does this help? As far as I know, only Oracle knows what this means (for example, what `qmxptAddDependency1` means). This may be helpful when communicating with Oracle Support, although OS should be able to reproduce the bug and see the full error message for themselves.

Comment: Search results for `qmxptAddDependency1` include a My Oracle Support note. I don't have access, but from the title it appears to cover this exact scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very likely an Oracle bug; ORA-00600 usually denotes an unhandled exception in the internal code written by the Oracle developers (not a bug caused by the "user", in this case you). Your best bet is to talk to Oracle Support (if you are a paying customer; I am not, for example). They may recognize the bug quickly, and tell you which patch to apply, assuming there is one already. Otherwise they will have to work on it.

In the meantime, you can move the subquery to a WITH clause. It will not work there either, but you can use the (undocumented?) hint MATERIALIZE, like so:

```
with
  list (id) as 
       ( select /*+ materialize */ id                -- notice the hint here!
         from   json_table('[1244, 1188]', '$[*]' columns(id number path '$')))
select *
from   your_table
where  id in (select id from list)
;
```

This does work. If you talk to Oracle Support, you can mention this as well; it will give them some thoughts on what may be wrong (although they may be able to do that on their own, as I did). The issue is "query transformation" - the optimizer tries to merge the subquery into the query, in a way that was coded incorrectly by the Oracle developers (most likely).

Of course, this is not a **solution**, it is only a **workaround**.